# file path error from created folder/subfolder with loop

Tags: python, loops, directory, path

I have a loop that creates multiple folders/sub-folders and csv. I was able to create folder/sub-folders with {date} and (tag) using os.

However, when I try to use the created file path for the cvs generated from the loop, i get

> Cannot save file into a non-existent directory:
> '/home/user/Desktop/test/(date)/(tag)

moi, m24or when i switch from (date)/(tag) to {date}/{tag}, i get

> KeyError: 'date'

Both data and tag are variable which changes after each loop.

```
main_dir = f"/home/user/Desktop/test/{date}/"
os.makedirs(main_dir + str(tag))


filepath = r'/home/user/Desktop/test/(date)/(tag)/{}.csv'
df.to_csv(filepath.format(filename), index = True, header=True)
```

Comment: are your tags and date in `filepath` really supposed to be in round brackets?

Comment: I think his idea is to print values of that variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in your logic.

1. Never use predefine functions/variables as user define variable. Instead of Date rename your variable to file_date.
2. When you use raw string and wanted to display variable value, you have to use "format"

Please find the solution below.

```
main_dir = f"/home/user/Desktop/test/{file_date}/"
os.makedirs(main_dir + str(tag))

filepath = r'/home/user/Desktop/test/{}/{}/{}.csv'
print(filepath.format(file_date,tag,filename))
```

Comment: thank you, your solution works perfectly.  I wasn't aware that "format" can be used for folders too.